# Enumerate list with side notes

Tags: enumerate

I would like to do something similar to this:

[image]

Where the property and its name are in the same line (like for symmetry property) and between round brackets like here. How can I do it?

Comment: They're not all on the same line!

Comment: Ok, supposing that there is enough space for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to make the descriptions flush right by adding `\hfill` before, like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $ d(O_x,O_y) = d(O_y,O_x) $ \hfill (symmetry)
\end{enumerate}
```

With help of a new command:

```
\newcommand*{\itemtag}[1]{\hfill (\emph{#1})}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $ d(O_x,O_y) = d(O_y,O_x) $ \itemtag{symmetry}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work if the `\itemtag` doesn't fit on the same line.